# How to implement MySQL 'NOT EXISTS' query for Contact having 1 Category but not another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have front-end search form that allows users to search for Contacts given a number of search fields (name, address, email, categories, etc).  I now have the requirement to implement 'negative' category searches.  In other words, they can search for a Contact belonging to one category, but not another. An example would be to return all Contacts assigned to "category_1" and not assigned to "category_2".  They do this by entering in a front-end html form field like so: "category_1, -category_2" (notice the minus sign).

I am attempting to use the NOT EXIST function in MySQL because I need the "negative filter" in the WHERE clause (for several reasons). Below is my attempt to implement.  Any idea why this is producing zero results?

For clarity, my table arrangement is as follows (many-to-many):
Contact -> ContactCategories <- Category

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    contact.*
FROM
    Contact contact
    INNER JOIN ContactCategory categories ON contact.ContactId = categories.ContactId
    INNER JOIN Category category ON categories.CategoryId = category.CategoryId
WHERE
    LOWER(category.Name) = 'category_1'
    AND NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT
            contact_temp.*
        FROM
            Contact contact_temp
            INNER JOIN ContactCategory categories_temp ON contact_temp.ContactId = categories_temp.ContactId
            INNER JOIN Category category_temp ON categories_temp.CategoryId = category_temp.CategoryId
        WHERE
            LOWER(category_temp.Name) = 'category_2'
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correlate the subquery with the main query.

There's no need to select from `Contact` in the subquery, just select from `ContactCategory` and correlate that with `categories_temp.ContactId = contact.ContactId`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    contact.*
FROM
    Contact contact
    INNER JOIN ContactCategory categories ON contact.ContactId = categories.ContactId
    INNER JOIN Category category ON categories.CategoryId = category.CategoryId
WHERE
    LOWER(category.Name) = 'category_1'
    AND NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT *
        FROM
            Contact contact_temp
            INNER JOIN ContactCategory categories_temp ON contact_temp.ContactId = categories_temp.ContactId
            INNER JOIN Category category_temp ON categories_temp.CategoryId = category_temp.CategoryId
        WHERE
            contact_temp.ContactId = contact.ContactId
            AND LOWER(category_temp.Name) = 'category_2'
    )
```

Comment: Brilliant.  This did the trick!

Comment: I will say the underlying code is generated via HQL so it can be quite verbose and sometimes inefficient for particular searches.

Comment: Any chance you could modify your answer to include the Contact & Category tables in the subquery - and not the ContactCategory table?  Reason is I will need to filter for Contact.TeamId and the HQL configuration doesn't have the m-to-m ContactCategory table setup as an relational entity.  This would be a huge help in not having to modify those entities and make use of HQL

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of your code is repeated.  For that reason I wouldn't use `NOT EXISTS()`

Instead you can just use a single *(non-correlated)* sub-query to check both conditions, and join the results on to the the `contact` table.

*Note:* I've also removed the `DISTINCT` keyword.  It's often used to hide either faulty queries or faulty data; fix the fault, don't fudge the query.

```
SELECT
  contact.*
FROM
  Contact contact
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    categories.ContactId
  FROM
    ContactCategory categories
  INNER JOIN
    Category        category
      ON categories.CategoryId = category.CategoryId
  WHERE
    LOWER(category.Name) IN ('category_1', 'category_2')
  GROUP BY
    categories.ContactId
  HAVING
        MAX(CASE WHEN LOWER(category.Name) = 'category_1' THEN 1 END) = 1
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN LOWER(category.Name) = 'category_2' THEN 1 END) = 0
)
  category_search
    ON contact.ContactId = category_search.ContactId
```

Also, be aware that using `LOWER(category.Name)` inhibits the use of indexes on that table.  You're better off having `lower_name` as an indexed column and searching that directly, without embedding the `LOWER()` in your query.

Comment: Good to know on the LOWER() indexing.  I will make that change!  Also, I recognize your query may be more efficient, but I do need to keep the criteria in the WHERE clause as their are MANY other fields (and supporting code) that relies on the filters being only in the WHERE clause.  For this reason, we are okay with sacrificing efficiency for maintainability.

Comment: @burton This pattern is extensible using lists and generalisations. If you're unable to generalise this to fit your needs, open another question with some added details and I'll be happy to demonstrate. It's a pattern I've used flexibly for significantly more complex needs.